# Why is the Win32 mutex so time-consuming

Tags: c++, c, windows, synchronization, mutex

I have been reading the book of Windows via C/C++. In chapter 8, page 215, the author compared the performance of various synchronization mechanisms. And I found the poor performance of mutex. When 4 threads run simultaneously, it spent more than **twenty three seconds** for the mutex synchronization.

Why is the Win32 mutex so time-consuming? And when can we use a mutex?

PS: I posted the test code in GitHub: https://gist.github.com/985198

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Spends more than twenty three seconds over how long? That value means nothing without context

Comment: If you write a benchmark that creates several threads that all try to acquire the same mutex, you will find that the performance goes down the tubes.  Such a benchmark is usually not reflective of real-world programs.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp : I wonder what make the performance of mutex goes down the tubes.And In real-world programs,how should we use the mutex?

Comment: @thinkthy: The performance goes down the tubes because you have several processors trying to simultaneously access the same mutex.  This happens whether you use critical sections, mutexes, or atomic variables — the performance of all of them goes down.  This doesn't matter as much in most real world programs because real world programs spend most of their time doing work instead of acquiring mutexes.  As for how to use the mutex — use it when it is necessary.

Comment: Note that this is twenty three seconds for four million mutex synchronizations, not four. (According to the posted code)

Comment: @Billy ONeal : Yes, you're right. I should read the code carefully.

Comment: @R.: That's why you're supposed to use critical sections. Cross process bits are rare in Windows land because you generally are supposed to use threads rather than processes to get things done. Windows does not implement `fork` which is really the only main scenario where you'd want to commonly have cross process locks. How else are you going to copy the reference to the mutex into the other process if not by name? If it's going to be nameable, it's going to have to act under the guise of the object manager.

Comment: `fork` would not help either; you need shared memory for process-shared userspace locking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mutex in Win32 is a kernel object, meaning that every use of it (`Wait`, `Release`) requires a system call that switches into kernel mode and back to user mode. Plus if your thread actually has to wait for the mutex, it loses its quantum while another thread that can run gets scheduled on the CPU. On WinXP and earlier (and maybe some later versions of Windows), mutexes were "fair", meaning that if your thread was last to wait for a mutex, it would be the last to receive it, further increasing the potential for contention.

The reasons to use a mutex are that you can easily share them between processes, you can be notified when the thread owning it is killed, and you can wait on them along with other objects using `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Note that your use of them in this benchmark is *not* the ideal way to use them because the overhead of just acquiring a mutex is way more than the amount of work you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

Because mutexes are kernel objects, all operations on them require a context switch. Such operations are relatively expensive. The rule of thumb is that when you need share resources between threads in the same process, use CRITICAL_SECTION objects. When you need to share resources between threads in different processes, then use Win32 mutexes.

Comment: @Dietruch: In NT land "Kernel Object" has specific semantics -- namely that it's managed by the [NT Object Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)) -- not that "the kernel touches it". Jorgen's answer is correct.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: A futex in Linux is CRITICAL_SECTION in Windows.

Comment: This operation of context switch does takes time, but it is unimaginable that synchronization time for just four threads  took over 23 seconds (My CPU is Core 2 Duo T7100).

Comment: @thinkhy: That sounds like a problem with the test. My machine does at least fifty thousand operations on a mutex/second, and I'm running a ton of other crap on this machine at the moment.... can you post the code?

Comment: @hackworks, no, a futex in Linux is a keyed event in windows (used in Vista's SRW locks). A CRITICAL_SECTION is an atomic compare-exchange fastpath coupled with a Mutex-based (or Event-based, etc) slow path.

Comment: @Billy ONeal : I have posted the test code in GitHub: gist.github.com/985198

Comment: @thinkhy : Pay more attention to this function: http://pastebin.com/iLtq0qKB -- You're doing **one million** mutex operations concurrently on four threads which takes 23 seconds (which comes out to ~173,000 synchronization operations per second). Still slow compared to critical sections but certainly not 23 seconds for 4 synchronizations.

Comment: @thinkhy: It should also be noted that the "volatile" tests **do not provide synchonization** -- not sure where you got this code, but don't think `volatile` provides any sort of threading protection. `volatile` does not allow the compiler to perform reordering but it does not provide the memory barrier you need on superscalar CPUs (e.g. anything newer than a Pentium chip). Also, you've got some undefined behavior on line 66 -- that should be a `delete []` rather than `delete`.

Comment: A context switch only happens when a wait is performed. Releasing a mutex and acquiring an available mutex don't require a CS.

Comment: @Gabe: Got anything to back that up? Because getting to the mutex itself through `Ob` probably requires a context switch on it's own.

Comment: @Billy: I wrote a program that does nothing but `Wait` on a mutex and `Release` it in a tight loop. It was able to do 700k wait/release cycles per second, or 1.4M calls/sec. While running it, I monitored the number of context switches/sec for the main thread, and it averaged about 130/sec, which is about what you'd expect for a system with a 10ms thread quantum.

Comment: @Billy ONeal : Jeffrey Richter wrote this code just for the purpose of teaching. Volatile does not provide any synchonization,and not use any cache line as well. The code snippet of volatile test is the basic unit of execution. Its performance is unaffected by the impact of multi-threaded scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

CRITICAL_SECTION is a spinlock which spins in userspace to acquire a lock. If it fails to get the lock at the end of spinning (limited by spin count), it gets into an wake-able wait (WaitForSingleObject()). Hence, for short sections of code you want to protect (critical section name comes from it) CRITICAL_SECTION is the way to go. If you plan to do IO and other time consuming tasks, CRITICAL_SECTION versus mutex/semaphore does not give you any savings.

Comment: It does not create a mutex or semaphore. It simply yields. (e.g. by calling `sleep(0)`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: The following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683476(v=vs.85).aspx says it calls a WaitForSingleObject(). Not sure if is specific to heap or CRITICAL_SECTION from the link though.

Comment: @Hackworks: `WaitForSingleObject` does not create a mutex or semaphore. It simply yields.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I get it, thanks. It executes a wait on some other kernel object since WaitForSingleObject() requires one. Wonder what that kernel object is though?

Comment: @Hackworks: My guess would be a change notification or an event. Not sure though. It might also be presented that way in the docs to explain to people what's going on, but not actually do that internally -- the innards of what's going on are always going to be an implementation detail.

Comment: @Billy: It's actually an event that it creates. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542796(v=VS.85).aspx for a flag that lets you have the events created when `CRITICAL_SECTION` objects are created rather than once the spin count runs out.